# Is there any way to extract this argument when passing a function as an argument to a curried function?

Tags: javascript

I just learned about function currying in JavaScript.

I do method calls such as:

```
yoHello('m', 'j') //prints m followed by j in the console

yoHello('m', 'j')('k') // prints TypeError: yoHello(...) is not a function
```

JS code:

```
function yoHello() {
  for (var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arguments[i] == "string") {
      console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
    else { //assume function
      console.log([].slice.call(arguments[i],0)); //TypeError: yoHello(...) is not a function
    }
  }
}
```

How do I change *yoHello* so that it extracts out the 'k' argument when it is passed as above?  Also, how should I view 'k' when it is being passed as above - is it an argument of an anonymous function?  Or should it be viewed as an argument to another instance of *yoHello*?

Comment: So far there is no way to distinguish `yoHello('m', 'j')` and `yoHello('m', 'j')('k')` by just  looking at `yoHello('m', 'j')` part... Your really can't return function and not a function at the same time... Some clarification is needed.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That's just syntactically wrong.. Can't you just pass `yoHello('m', 'j', 'k')`?

Answer (score 0):

Currying works by returning a function from a function.  For example;

```
function add(x){
    return function(y){
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Which you could use as follows;

```
add(1)(2) // = 3
```

Why would you use this?  So that you can set `x` for reuse and then input different values of `y`;

```
add1 = add(1);
add1(2) // = 3
add1(9) // = 10
```

If you want to just print out the variables put in, you could do;

```
function yoHello(){
    var args1 = arguments;
    return function(){
        args2 = arguments;
        for (var i = 0; i<args1.length; i++) {
            console.log(args1[i]);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i<args2.length; i++) {
            console.log(args2[i]);
        }
    }
}

yoHello('m', 'j')('k') // logs:  m \n j \n k
yo = yoHello('m','j')
yo('k') // logs:  m \n j \n k
```

Or alternately;

```
function yoHello(){
    var args1 = arguments;
    for (var i = 0; i<args1.length; i++) {
        console.log(args1[i]);
    }
    return function(){
        args2 = arguments;
        for (var i = 0; i<args2.length; i++) {
            console.log(args2[i]);
        }
    }
}

yoHello('m', 'j')('k') // logs:  m \n j \n k
yo = yoHello('m','j') // logs: m \n j
yo('k') // logs: k
```